# How to serialize a struct with a top-level key with Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm currenlty developping a web API with Rocket that use the following struct for error responses :

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ErrorResponse {
    code: u16,
    reason: &'static str,
    #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
    description: Option<String>,
}
```

Actually, serializing this struct produce json similar to this :

```json
{
  "code": 400,
  "reason": "Bad Request"
}
```

I'm looking to serialize it this way:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "reason": "Bad Request"
  }
}
```

**What is the easiest way to do that without using two different sructs ?**

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Im not sure its possible unless you implement your own serialization/deserialization for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to wrap your struct in an `enum` with a single struct variant:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum ErrorResponseWrapper {
    #[serde(rename = "error")]
    ErrorResponse {
        code: u16,
        reason: &'static str,
        #[serde(skip_serializing_if = "Option::is_none")]
        description: Option<String>,
    }
}
```

The annoying thing about this is that the type and the constructor must have different names now. I.e. if a function takes an `ErrorResponse` it now has to take an `ErrorResponseWrapper` (although you probably wanna come up with a better name than that), but you have to construct such a value with the `ErrorResponseWrapper::ErrorResponse` variant. Fortunately you can at least add `use ErrorResponseWrapper::ErrorResponse;` to your imports.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=87d187595453bc7f43f54985aabebebd)

Comment: Nice, probably he could just reexport Error response only and that would be it.

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't thought of turning it into an enum. Thanks for the fast answer!